# Creating a dynamic drop-down list based on an array expression

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, forms

Would it be possible in a QGIS form to create a list of values with the `array()` function in the expression builder? This array would change, depending on different conditions.

The Value Relation widget is close to what I need, but it has to have one connected table, and the values in the list are only from this table. I'd like to add multiple conditions and values modifications.

Let's say I have 3 layers:

- **infra**, where i'll find the *type* of infrastructure

| geometry | "type" |
| --- | --- |
| line | 'underground' |
|  | 'aerial' |

- **telecomLines**, where I'll find the *size* of the lines.

| geometry | "size" |
| --- | --- |
| line | 'big' |
|  | 'small' |

- **equipment** the layer i'll have to edit, where l'll choose the type of *equipment* to install, I would need an array of possible object to install depending on the intersected *type* and *size*. Id like the array to be used as a scrolling menu in the form when creating or editing a point. Depending on the intersecting lines, a filtered list of possible choices would appear.

| geometry | "equipment" |
| --- | --- |
| point | 'big pole' |
|  | 'large pole' |
|  | 'high pole' |
|  | 'small pole' |
|  | 'thin pole' |
|  | 'low pole' |
|  | 'big chambre' |
|  | 'large chamber' |
|  | 'deep chamber' |
|  | 'small chamber' |
|  | 'thin chamber' |
|  | 'shallow chamber' |

For exemple, for *big* and *underground* cables, an array of possible big chambers, and for *small* and *aerial* cables, an array of possible small telecom poles.

This Expression would produce the array of possible *equipment* on a the **equipment** layer when opening an form.

```
with_variable('lineType',
            aggregate(
                layer:='infra', 
                aggregate:='max', 
                expression:="type", 
                filter:=intersects( $geometry, geometry(@parent) )),

with_variable('linesSize',
            aggregate(
                layer:='telecomLines', 
                aggregate:='max', 
                expression:="size", 
                filter:=intersects( $geometry, geometry(@parent) )),

if (@lineType = 'underground',
         map_get( map(  'big', array('big chambre', 'large chamber', 'deep chamber'),
                        'small', array('small chamber', 'thin chamber', 'shallow chamber')), 
                @lineType),
if (@lineType = 'aerial',
        map_get( map(   'big', array('big pole', 'large pole', 'high pole'),
                        'small', array('small pole', 'thin pole', 'low pole')), 
                @linesSize),
--(Else)
array('big pole', 'large pole', 'high pole', 'small pole',
        'thin pole', 'low pole', 'big chambre', 'large chamber', 'deep chamber',
        'small chamber', 'thin chamber', 'shallow chamber')))))
```

here's a quick map of the exemple on qgis Cloud:

https://qgiscloud.com/nox/filterList/?bl=mapnik&l=telecomLines%2Cequipment%2Cinfra&t=filterList&e=172490%2C6003875%2C174522%2C6004867

Comment: The short answer is: Yes. The more detailed answer is based on what you need: please edit your question and add more details.

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: Your expression is valid and produces an output (array). So what is your question? It would also help to see your data structure - or even better have some sample data.

Comment: For example: does your "type" field contain numeric values? Without seeing the setting, I have to try to reproduce a setting that probably will not correspond to what you have. It's also difficult to imagine how the interesction of the two layer looks like: line and point?

Comment: Id like the array to be used as a scrolling menu in the form when creating or editing a point. Depending on the intersecting lines, a filtered list of possible choices would appear.

Comment: You can use the filter in the value relation widget. A good example that shows how to do it is the video here: https://www.northrivergeographic.com/archives/qgis-3-2-drive-down-lists-aka-value-relation-widget

Comment: the value relation widget works fine but it has to have a relation to a table. I was wondering if this table could be replaced by an expression. This way I could easily share the .qml style with co-workers, without explaining how to find and insert the table needed for the value relation widget to work.

Comment: I guess to fully understand your problem, I would need to see a screenshot: the two lines infra and telecomlines are identical (as geometries)? You create the equipment points on one/both of these lines?

Comment: I did a small exemple on QGIS cloud if you want to see what it looks like: https://qgiscloud.com/nox/filterList/?bl=mapnik&l=telecomLines%2Cequipment%2Cinfra&t=filterList&e=172490%2C6003875%2C174522%2C6004867

Comment: I suggest that you get the information of the layers `infra` and `telecomLines` as attributes in your `equipment` layer, creating new attributes: `array_first ( overlay_nearest( 'infra', type))`. You than have all the information in one layer.